# PHP Display array_diff data in a HTML Table

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP Code:

```
$notIn1 = array_diff($ListData2, $ListData1);
```

the `$ListData2` and `$ListData1` variables are arrays of data.

i am currently displaying the data like:

```
echo implode('<br>', $notIn1);
```

but i want to display it in a table

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($notIn1 as $line) {
    echo '<tr><td>$line</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```